# VB.net find same key in all dictionarys

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

Hey all i have about 4 dicionarys holding values for variuos things. Each dictionary has the same key for each item within each of the 4 dictionary.

Example:

```
dictionary1 (string, string):
  key = 523697777, value = "bobs burgers"
  key = 89557, value = "Blah blah 1"
  key = 598823644, value = "something"

dictionary2 (string, string):
  key = 523697777, value = "oats and honey"
  key = 89557, value = "juicyfruit"
  key = 598823644, value = "sun glasses"

dictionary3 (string, datetime):
  key = 523697777, value = 01/05/2013 00:00:00
  key = 89557, value = 01/24/2013 00:00:00
  key = 598823644, value = 03/12/2013 00:00:00

dictionary4 (string, string):
  key = 523697777, value = "Computers"
  key = 89557, value = "IM"
  key = 598823644, value = "cans"
```

Now i want to be able to just loop and get the correct value from each dicionary without having to loop through each dicionary seprate.

Currenly i am doing this:

```
Dim allTogether As New StringBuilder

For Each dict1 In dictionary1 
   For Each dict2 In dictionary2 
      If dict1.Key = dict2.Key Then
          allTogether.Append(dict1.Value)
          allTogether.Append(dict2.Value)

          For Each dict2 In dictionary3
             If dict2.Key = dict3.Key Then
                 allTogether.Append(dict3.Value)

                 For Each dict2 In dictionary3
                    If dict3.Key = dict4.Key Then
                      allTogether.Append(dict4.Value)
                    End If
                 Next
             End If
          Next
      End If
   Next
Next
```

Should produce:

```
 bobs burgers  oats and honey  01/05/2013 00:00:00  Computers
 Blah blah 1   juicyfruit      01/24/2013 00:00:00  IM
 something     sun glasses     03/12/2013 00:00:00  cans
```

Is it possible to get the data in one swoop?

Comment: So basically given a key you want to get values from all 4 dictionaries for the same key?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the keys:

```
Dim keys = dictionary1.Keys
```

Iterate over them:

```
For Each key In Keys
```

Construct result (here: print to console):

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}",
                      dictionary1(key),
                      dictionary2(key),
                      dictionary3(key),
                      dictionary4(key))
```

End loop.

```
Next
```

Comment: @StealthRT Doesn’t matter, still works. What’s important is that they *keys* are the same (type, and actual value).

Comment: Error on "key" **Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, Date)' cannot be converted to 'String'.**

Comment: @StealthRT You’re doing something wrong, look at my code again. You’re not iterating over the keys, you’re iterating over a *dictionary*.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the keys definitely exist in all four dictionaries all of the time then as a suggestion, why not :

```
Public Structure myStruct
    Public thing1 As String
    Public thing2 As String
    Public dateThing As DateTime
    Public thing3 As String
End Structure

Private myDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, myStruct)
```

if you are not guaranteed to have the same keys in all dictionaries, why not just use the features of the dictionary?

```
If dictionary1.ContainsKey(someKey) Then allTogether.Append(dictionary1(someKey))
```

etc.

Comment: At some point one dicinary may not have the same key as all the others.

Comment: @StealthRT then note that the other answers here will throw a `KeyNotFoundException` if that is ever the case.  Using `.ContainsKey` as above allows you to check before you try to extract a value for a nonexistent key.

Comment: @StealthRT with this option, you just need to set the strings or the date to null if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work - if you still need to use stringbuilder.

```
For Each sKey In Dictionary1.Keys
    allTogether.Append(Dictionary1(sKey))
    allTogether.Append(Dictionary2(sKey))
    allTogether.Append(Dictionary3(sKey))
    allTogether.Append(Dictionary4(sKey))
    allTogether.Append("---------------")
Next
```

I've added last "--------------" as separator between sets.